# Find a discontinuous linear map on $c_0$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I want to find a  discontinuous linear map $\phi: c_0 \to \mathbb{C}$. where $c_0$ has sup norm obviously, $\|.\|_\infty$

I can't think of any example. please suggest me one. I ll try checking it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract solution ([apparently it is not possible a concrete example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#Axiom_of_choice)): take a Hamel basis of $c_0$, $(b_i)_{i\in I}$ with $\Bbb N\subset I$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|b_n\|=0$ (why this is possible?).

For each
$$x=\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i b_i\in c_0$$
take
$$\phi(x)=\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i.$$
The sequence $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\to 0$ but $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1.$$